# How to create search functionality like Google Play Store

Tags: android

How would I go about creating a search function like Google implemented on the Play Store? I want exactly the same functionality - click a search icon at the top of screen which then displays an inputText field with suggestions that are overlayed on top of the background app.

Please help!

Justin.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use ActionBar and AutoCompleteTextView... look it up.

Answer (score 0):

For search functionality You can use `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
ArrayList<String> mcontact_arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayAdapter<String> mcontactarray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.row_text, mcontact_arraylist);
            mAutoCompleteText.setAdapter(mcontactarray);
```

This will help you to achive above functionality.